# Whats difference between HL7 v2.5 and v2.8

Tags: hl7, hl7-v2

Whats difference between HL7 version 2.5 and 2.8. I searched on google, but couldn't get any good information on this.
We need to migrate to 2.8, and wondering how much impact we would have because of this change.

Comment: Have you looked at Health Level Seven's website?

Comment: I looked at the HL7 website. They have details on what features are in HL7 v2.8.. however they do not have a good way to say, what all things are getting changed between 2 versions.. Also, they dont have comparison page where you can compare any 2 versions

Answer (score 1):

All HL7v2 versions are backwards compatible, meaning that if you assert that you are using 2.8, a 2.5 message should automatically be valid in 2.8.

That said, HL7v2 implementations may be making rules/assumptions that don't follow anything in the spec.

From HL7v2.7 Chapter 1.8.1

> The usage of multiple versions of HL7 2.x within a single integration infrastructure creates further anomalies that are introduced as the Standard has evolved. While all attempts have been made to maintain “backwards compatibility” it is clearly a goal that cannot be completely achieved. For example, documentation exists within HL7 2.x that, after several years of continued support, has retired older data types with newer definitions that support more comprehensive properties including requirements for all countries using HL7.

You state that you need to migrate to 2.8. The only reason you would need to upgrade is if you have need of a new field added in a version between 2.5 and 2.8.

Chapter 1 of each HL7 version spec usually contains errata and breaking changes between versions.

Comment: We need to support one of our interface for a new customer, who is asking for v2.8.. Although I don't have exact specs from the new client yet, but based on communication with them, they did mention new fields need to be supported which are not there in 2.5